# Using URL in a LaTeX bibtex file

Tags: bibtex, urls

I'm using bibtex for my bibliography in LaTeX. I would like to use URL's and I need to cite. How do I add URLs into the .bib file. Also, I am using chicago as a bibliographystyle. I wrote the following code, but It does not show up in my refreneces. How can I fix it?

```
 \begin{filecontents*}{mybib1.bib}
 @misc{bworld,
 author = {Ingo Lütkebohle},
 title = {{BWorld Robot Control Software}},
 howpublished = "\url{http://aiweb.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/content/bworld-
 robot-control-software/}",
 year = {2008}, 
 }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

 The information is available in \citep{bworld}. 

\bibliographystyle{chicago} 
\bibliography{mybib1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\citep{bworld}` *not* `\citep{Ingo Lütkebohle}`, since the citekey that you've defined is `bworld`. Does that fix it?

Comment: Thnaks for your comment, but it does not solve the orblem.

Comment: Are you using a package for citing things? If I add, for example, `\usepackage{natbib}`, your MWE compiles just fine for me.

Comment: Yes, I am using \usepackage{natbib}. I did not recieve any error, but it does does appear in my document. Just I have (?) in my text.

Comment: Have you run `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex` on your document?  If you are seeing something like **??**, that usually means you have not run the full sequence of commands.  (Either that, or you are citing an entrykey that does not exist in your `.bib` file, as Adam suggested.)

Comment: `BibLaTeX` knows about url's for all entry types and has a `biblatex-chicago` extension.

Comment: Please always post **complete** code. That is much more useful that a fragment as the discussion in these comments is demonstrating. People should need to guess you are using `natbib` or whatever. Why make it difficult for people to help you? Note that complete need not be large. Just enough to show your issue when compiled. But it should compile unless failure to compile is the problem you are asking about! For example, the document class and other packages are clearly relevant here.

Comment: Seconding what @cfr said! Here's a link explaining what a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is. Hope that's helpful! And see [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number). Your code should compile just fine if you run the correct compilation sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Too long for a comment and needed markup</sub>

Compile the following code (saved as `myfile.tex`) with

```
pdflatex myfile
bibtex myfile
pdflatex myfile
pdflatex myfile
```

Contents of `myfile.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{mybib1.bib}
 @misc{bworld,
 author = {Ingo Lütkebohle},
 title = {{BWorld Robot Control Software}},
 howpublished = "\url{http://aiweb.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/content/bworld-
 robot-control-software/}",
 year = {2008},
 }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

 The information is available in \citep{bworld}.

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{mybib1}
\end{document}
```

[image]